# Trying get WITH RECURSIVE working in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I'm trying to follow the examples in this article: https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-query-hierarchical-data

I've constructed a simple table in PostgreSQL to hold hierarchical data:

```
media_set_id (uuid)
name (citext)
parent_id (uuid and NULL allowed)
```

This is the query I constructed:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
  SELECT media_set_id AS id,
         name,
         parent_id,
         CAST (name AS citext) AS path
  FROM media_sets
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  
  UNION ALL
     
  SELECT media_sets.media_set_id,
         media_sets.name,
         media_sets.parent_id,
         hierarchy.path || '\' || media_sets.name
  FROM media_sets, hierarchy
  WHERE media_sets.parent_id = hierarchy.id
)

SELECT * FROM hierarchy;
```

The table is populated with some sample data.

When I run the query, I get this error: **relation "hierarchy" does not exist**

I can't figure out what's wrong with my SQL code.  Any ideas?

Robert

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting your code a little you  get the result you intended.

> ```
> CREATE tABLE media_sets (
> media_set_id uuid,
> name text,
> parent_id uuid )
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
>   SELECT media_set_id AS id,
>          name,
>          parent_id,
>          CAST (name AS text) AS path
>   FROM media_sets
>   WHERE parent_id IS NULL
>   
>   UNION ALL
>      
>   SELECT media_sets.media_set_id,
>          media_sets.name,
>          media_sets.parent_id,
>          hierarchy.path || '\' || media_sets.name
>   FROM media_sets JOIN hierarchy
>   ON media_sets.parent_id = hierarchy.id
> )
>
> SELECT * FROM hierarchy;
> ```

> ```
> id | name | parent_id | path
> :- | :--- | :-------- | :---
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=09246e388e3172a875890cff31a250b4)*

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... this alternate approach does work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
  SELECT media_set_id,
         name,
         parent_id
  FROM media_sets
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  
  UNION ALL
     
  SELECT ms.media_set_id,
         ms.name,
         ms.parent_id
  FROM media_sets ms
  INNER JOIN hierarchy h on ms.parent_id = h.media_set_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM hierarchy;
```

I'm not really sure why this works and the other does not but I can work with this version as it's returning the records in the order I need to construct a hierarchical tree in the UI.

Comment: I spoke too soon!  This code, which I copied & pasted elsewhere for safekeeping is now suddenly not working. I'm getting a "syntax error at or near ")" ".

So frustrating!!!

Comment: OMG apparently there can be no blank rows between any lines!  I didn't think this mattered for SQL but maybe this is a DBeaver thing, which is the DB client I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one thing it does not do is sort the data in the way I ideally need.  What I was hoping for was for the hierarchy to be returned like this:

```
root
parent1
child1_of_parent1
child2_of_parent1
parent2
child1_of_parent2
child1_of_child1_of_parent2
child2_of_child1_of_parent2
child2_of_parent2
```

If anyone knows how to force such an order of records to be returned, that's the last piece of the puzzle I'm looking to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for really flubbing up this Q&A.  But out of completeness I feel it appropriate to provide a final set of SQL code which I know works, as it may help someone `nbk` for the assist!

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
  SELECT media_set_id,
         name,
         parent_id,
         cast (name as text) as path
  FROM media_sets
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ms.media_set_id,
         ms.name,
         ms.parent_id,
         h.path || '\' || ms.name
  FROM media_sets ms
  INNER JOIN hierarchy h on ms.parent_id = h.media_set_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM hierarchy
ORDER BY path;
```

The final `ORDER BY` returns the records in a way that will allow me to build a hierarchical UI and populate the tree from top to bottom.